# must be either xts-coercible or timebased

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have this kind of data:

```
Date Time           Value
02-09-17 14:17:20   92
02-09-17 14:17:20   91
02-09-17 14:17:20   38.62391
02-09-17 14:17:20   120.3348
02-09-17 14:17:20   18.1
02-09-17 14:17:20   11.2
02-09-17 14:26:40   97
02-09-17 14:26:40   102
02-09-17 14:26:40   38.62254
02-09-17 14:26:40   120.3719
02-09-17 14:26:40   18.1
02-09-17 14:26:40   11.2
02-09-17 14:30:09   103
02-09-17 14:30:09   103
02-09-17 14:30:09   38.62012
02-09-17 14:30:09   120.3853
02-09-17 14:30:09   18.1
02-09-17 14:30:09   11.3
02-09-17 14:37:00   102
02-09-17 14:37:00   103
02-09-17 14:37:00   38.61536
02-09-17 14:37:00   120.4119
02-09-17 14:37:00   18.1
02-09-17 14:37:00   11.3
02-09-17 14:41:30   101
02-09-17 14:41:30   101
02-09-17 14:41:30   38.61232
02-09-17 14:41:30   120.4295
02-09-17 14:41:30   18.1
02-09-17 14:41:30   11.3
02-09-17 14:46:59   99
02-09-17 14:46:59   98
02-09-17 14:46:59   38.60936
02-09-17 14:46:59   120451
02-09-17 14:46:59   18.1
02-09-17 14:46:59   11.3
02-09-17 14:51:20   97
02-09-17 14:51:20   96
```

and I want to resample every 10 minutes.

```
mydata <- read_csv('~/dd.csv')
mydata$`Date Time` <- as.POSIXct(mydata$`Date Time`, "%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")

mydata <- mydata[endpoints(mydata, "minutes", 10)]
```

and I am receiving:

> Error in try.xts(x, error = "must be either xts-coercible or
>   timeBased") : must be either xts-coercible or timeBased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

You have to transform data to as_xts and define date column:

```
newdata <- as_xts(thedata, date_col = `Date Time`)
newdata <- newdata[endpoints(newdata, "minutes", 10)]
```